# Why is data being lost in socket.io?

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, socket.io, flask-socketio

I'm building a small app that tails a log and displays it on the client. However, when I append lines to my log, I lose some data.

Here's the relevant Python handler:

```
@socketio.on('Request logs')
def handle_request_logs():
    logfile = '/path/to/some_log.log'

    # gets last 25 lines from logfile
    last_n_lines = tailer.tail(open(logfile), 25)

    # sends the initial 25 lines
    emit('Initial send', { 'lines' : last_n_lines })

    # emits lines that were appended to logfile
    @copy_current_request_context
    def tail(logfile):
        for line in tailer.follow(open(logfile)):
            print("About to emit {0}".format(line))
            emit('log', { 'line' : line })

    # emit added lines as they come
    t = threading.Thread(target=tail, args=(logfile,))
    t.start()
```

and here's the JS that receives `'log'`:

```
  socket.on('log', function(data) {
      alert("Got some data: ", data['line']);
  });
```

Whenever I append something to the log (for instance `echo 'hello, world!' >> /path/to/some_log.log`), I see an alert on the client with the message
`"Got some data: "`. However, my server prints `"About to emit hello, world!"`.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a comma in your alert (javascript).  It should probably be a + for concatenation.

Comment: Ugh... I hate myself.